# Scrapy - Wait for ALL requests to be completed

Tags: python, scrapy

I just started using scrapy and I am trying to scrape several links which when yields my JSON result. Simple enough, but my problem is with the asynchoronous nature of the requests. I am having trouble figuring out the proper structure to achieve this.

Everything works well in the following code except `yield Items` at the end of the parse method. This value is yeilded before any/all the requests are complete. Is there a way to say "wait for all requests to be completed" then yield. Or an "on finish scraping" method where I can can retrieve the final result?

```
class SpiderCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spiderman"
    allowed_domains = ["mywebsite.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.mywebsite.com/items",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="col"]'):
            items = MyItem()
            items['categories'] = []

            sections = sel.xpath('//tbody')
            category_count = 5 #filler

            for count in range(1, category_count):
                category = Category()
                #set categories
                for item, link in zip(items.xpath("text()"), items.xpath("@href")):
                    subItem = SubItem()
                    #set subItems
                    subItem['link'] = "www.mywebsite.com/nexturl"

                    #the problem
                    request = scrapy.Request(subItem['link'], callback=self.parse_sub_item)
                    request.meta['sub_item'] = subItem 
                    yield request

                    category['sub_items'].append(subItem)
                items['categories'].append(category)

        #I want this yield to not be executed until ALL requests are complete
        yield items

    def parse_sub_item(self, response):
        fields = #some xpath
        subItem = response.meta["sub_item"]
        subItem['fields'] = #some xpath
        subItem['another_field'] = #some xpath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind Scrapy is to export some items per request. What you are doing is you want everything together and return only one item -- and this is this way not possible.

However you can achieve what you want but with a bit altering of your code.
Export the items as they are currently and create an [item pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) for example which converts those items you yield in the `parse` method into one big item (dictionary?) containing the categories and their `sub_items` and export everything together when the `close_spider` method is called.

In this case you can handle async item processing and group your results together.

Comment: Thank you, I eventually figured out this approach, my thinking was too procedural at the time.